# CAShapeLayer draws a circle in center as a sideeffect of line cap set to kCALineJoinRound

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I'm drawing a segment of a pie chart with the following code:

```
CAShapeLayer *segment = [CAShapeLayer layer];
UIBezierPath *segmentPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

[segmentPath addArcWithCenter:segmentCenter radius:segmentRadius startAngle:angle1 endAngle:angle2 clockwise:YES];

segment.path = [segmentPath CGPath];
[segment setLineCap:kCALineJoinRound]; // this is the line which causes this

segment.lineWidth = 8;
segment.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
segment.strokeColor = [[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor];

[self.layer addSublayer:segment];
```

and as a sideffect of setting kCALineJoinRound I get also a little circle inside. I need to get rid of it, can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the problem was due to the CAShapeLayer being added twice in layoutSubviews which caused this strange effect.